# Create Table If Not Exists Hanging

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, amazon-rds

I am still new to using databases, but currently I am using a mysql database and attempting to make my bash script unbreakable because it might be used in several different environments (dev, qa, etc). I know it will run correctly without this one line.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
```

I also know that if I put that exact line into my database when that table does not exist then it runs perfectly and if it does exist already it gives me a warning, but does not break.

```
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1050 | Table 'backupfiles' already exists |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
```

When I run the line above and there is no table named backupfiles it works perfectly, but when there is it hangs(when I say hangs it sits there and does nothing) 95% of the time and 5% of the time works. Has anyone run into a problem like this? I am using AWS RDS(Amazon Web serices Relational Database Service) and the mysql server is  5.5.27

Here is all of my code that I relates to the mysql database

```
mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw <<QUERY_INPUT
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE;
use $DATABASE;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20), archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100), glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);
INSERT INTO backupfiles VALUES ('$archive_file_name', '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());
COMMIT;
QUERY_INPUT
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running ? Is the table InnoDB ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA this is in Amazon's Web Service's (AWS) Relational Database Service (RDS) and it is running mysql 5.5.27

Comment: Don't you mean `use $DATABASE;` instead of `use glacier;` ???

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA I missed that! I have been editing this section a lot today trying to fix this issue and earlier I hardcoded a few things, but the $DATABASE = 'glacier'

Comment: The answer to why this works inconsistently is probably just waiting for you to find it by running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` from another session while the connection is allegedly not reaponding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this troubling for two reasons

## **REASON #1**

This could be a bug that never got squashed out of MySQL 5.5.17

- **`Nov 08, 2011`** : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63144 (Status is Needs Triage on MySQL 5.5.17)
- **`Mar 21, 2011`** : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60563 (MySQL 5.5.10)
- **`Jun 23, 2006`** : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20662

## **REASON #2**

You are trying to acquire a metadata lock on an InnoDB table in an RDS environment? Ouch !!!

## **Possible Workaround**

Instead of trusting the metadata locking in RDS, ask the information_schema if the table exists already. Suppose the table is `mydb.backupfiles`. Run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='backupfiles';
```

If the answer comes back 0, run `CREATE TABLE backupfiles ...`. Otherwise, don't run it.

## **Possible Solution**

Upgrade to the Latest MySQL (5.6.12) or the Latest MySQL5.5 (5.5.31). Hopefully, this issue was solved in a more recent version

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-07-11 15:16 EDT

Here is a rewrite of your bash code to check if the table already exists

```
    echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DATABASE;" > /tmp/runthis.sql
    echo "use $DATABASE;" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
    SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables"
    SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema='${DATABASE}' AND table_name='backupfiles';"
    TABLE_EXISTS=`mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
    if [[ ${TABLE_EXISTS} -eq 0 ]]; then
      SQLSTMT="CREATE TABLE backupfiles (fileName VARCHAR(20),"
      SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} archiveId VARCHAR(500), checkSum VARCHAR(100),"
      SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} glacierVault VARCHAR(100), timeStamp date);"
      echo "${SQLSTMT}" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
    fi
    SQLSTMT="INSERT INTO backupfiles VALUES ('$archive_file_name',"
    SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} '$archiveID', '$CURRENTVAULT', '$checkSum', CURDATE());"
    echo "${SQLSTMT}" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
    echo "COMMIT;" >> /tmp/runthis.sql
    mysql -h portal-rds -u $user --password=$mysqlpw < /tmp/runthis.sql
```

Comment: So I can run this and it will return a value, I am not sure if I am searching with the wrong terms, but to simply put it where is the value it is returning being saved, or is there a way to save it so that I could put it in an if else statement?

Comment: Is the CREATE TABLE being launched in PHP or at the MySQL prompt ?

Comment: It is all via a bash script and I am in the MySQL prompt when it is called, I just updated the initial question to try and add clarifying details

Comment: I am sorry I have to go to a meeting right now, I'll back in about 40 minutes to answer this a little more.

Comment: That is fine, thank you so much for the help! I thought I fixed it but took out the create table if not exists line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9620/discussion-between-tall-paul-and-rolandomysqldba)